# Node request() not being sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the npm request library and am running into an issue where the request is never sent if I call express's res.send() after calling request. I realize the request callback won't fire if I close the connection, but I'm not even seeing the request being sent in the first place.

This code is being executed on RunKit (formerly TonicDev), an online code editor that allows code execution via endpoints. I'm not seeing this issue on my local machine, so it seems like it may have to do with RunKit. Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on here or how I might work around this?

You can execute the code yourself by going to:
https://runkit.com/gragland/58056bc6e9d9ed00130c84d5 and clicking the endpoint link at the top.

```
// Helper to return a RunKit compatible express app (runkit.com/tonic/express-endpoint)
var tonicExpress = require("@runkit/tonic/express-endpoint/1.0.0")
// Provide the exports object to the tonicExpress helper
var app = tonicExpress(module.exports)

var request = require('request')

app.get("/", function(req, res){

    var request_number = 9

 request({
    // To see if request is sent go to: https://requestb.in/1coqbqn1?inspect
    url: 'http://requestb.in/1coqbqn1', 
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        request_number: request_number,
        message: 'hello'
    }
})

// The line below has to be commented out for the above request to be sent
// I don't care about the request callback() firing, I just want the request to be sent
res.send('Done')   
})
```

Comment: Your doing res.send in your request(), but your also doing a res.send() that will close the connection,.  Either don't do res.send('done'), or in your request callback don't use res.send(),..  It's most likely crashing out trying to send to a closed connection otherwise.  Maybe replace your res.send() with console.log().  I assume RunKit has a way of seeing what the console log is doing.

Comment: Hey Keith, the issue is that the request is never even being sent in the first place, which I can tell be checking https://requestb.in/1coqbqn1?inspect. If I comment out res.send('done') then the request goes through and eventually res.send('Request Complete') is called. It's as if the actually firing off of the request is async (rather then just the response being async).

Comment: I think request is getting sent, but because it will error doing res.send again because the connection is already closed, maybe RunKit is not showing it.  What is it your trying to achieve, you either do res.send('done') connection closes, in this case you can't have res.send() in your request callback,. Or you wait until the request is done and do your res.send('Request Complete') you can't have both as it doesn't make any sense.  If you just do a console.log('here') inside your request callback, do you get anything?

Comment: I edited the code example above to make my intentions clearer. I don't care about the callback executing at all, I just want the request to be sent, which is not happening. My guess is that RunKit kills the node process when res.send is called and that happens before the actual request is sent out (maybe due to how Node internally deals with requests).